# How to use transactions in Silverstripe 3.3 with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, silverstripe

Does Silverstripe 3.3 support transactions with MySQL? If so, can it be used with the ORM?

I can't find any documentation on this subject. An example would be very nice.

Comment: This functionality should be buried deep in the ORM, the application should rarely bother with it. The whole point of ORMs is to hide these details from the users of the ORM. A quick search in the API documentation revealed that the mysql coonector class does have start / end / rollback transaction methods, so silverstripe is aware of this functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Shadow mentioned, you shouldn't need to worry about transactions as SilverStripe will handle them internally.

That being said, if you need to do something explicitly, you could do something like this:

```
try {
    DB::getConn()->transactionStart();

    // do stuff...

    DB::getConn()->transactionEnd();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    DB::getConn()->transactionRollback();
}
```

See `SS_Database` - [API documentation here](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.3/source-class-SS_Database.html#484-492).